# Must a croissant always be a crescent?

Tags: vocabulaire

I recently ordered a chocolate croissant from the menu of a French-owned coffeeshop, and when it arrived it turned out to be a pain au chocolat. The shop belongs to a chain that likes to market itself as authentically French, which got me wondering - would this happen in France?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you order a ***croissant*** (alone), that can't be a ***pain au chocolat*** but if you order a ***croissant au chocolat***, as no such thing is common (you have *croissants au jambon*, *croissants aux amandes* or *croissants au fromage* though), the closest thing that would be served would be indeed a ***pain au chocolat***.

*Pain au chocolat* is even actually sometimes called *croissant au chocolat* in eastern France (and [commonly in Canada outside Québec](https://francaisdenosregions.com/2017/01/13/chocolatine-a-conquis-le-quebec/)):

[image]

Source: Mathieu Avanzi [Francais de nos régions](https://francaisdenosregions.com/tag/croissant-au-chocolat/)

Comment: Thanks. This is the coffee shop's term though, not mine - it put "chocolate croissant" on the menu but served what I would call a "pain au chocolat". Chocolate croissants (croissants with a chocolate fondant filling) do exist where I am. From the original version of your answer (and LPH's answer below) it looks as though most French people do still link the name of the pastry with the shape, and would think the coffee shop was misusing the term. I think it may be an American thing.

Comment: Yes, I had never heard about *croissants* (crescent shape) with chocolate inside sold in *boulangeries* or coffee shops until I saw your question. Of course, no law forbids to sell such things and there are certainly places where you might find some in France, and even more outside France, like Spain where *viennoiseries* are common too.

Comment: @JD2000: I have come across the exact same term in Miami, in California and in New York, so I also think *chocolate croissant* has become the accepted term in the USA for a "pain au chocolat". In my last trip to the US, I have seen this term *croissant* used in a bakery for almost everything that looked like what the French would call "viennoiseries" (*croissant with raisins* for a "pain aux raisins", etc.).  I guess that, as *croissant* imported in English has lost its relationship to the crescent shape, we may see its meaning evolve to any pastry that looks vaguely French to US consumers.

Comment: Would it be safe to assume that "pain" does not convey a nice idea in English, whereas croissant not only does, but does it with a sense of "French class"? Marketing-wise, it seems to make absolute sense. As for the use of "croissant au chocolat", I've roamed France and Belgium for decades and this is the first time I've ever heard about it. Most people would just assume that you want a croissant split in two with a chocolate bar inside, or indeed, if you have a foreign accent, imagine that you are referring to a pain au chocolat.

Comment: @ledebutant I wouldn't say that, and in fact in the UK I have only ever seen chocolate croissant used for something that really is a chocolate croissant. Many people there think there is a pastry called a pan-oh and servers will say pan-oh chocolate (with chocolate pronounced exactly as in English) or pan-oh raisin (again with raisin pronounced exactly as in English) for a pain aux raisins - so they are not hearing pain in the sense of something very simple and basic (bread) or something negative (pain).

Comment: @ledebutant I agree that the cause is not the aptness of "croissant", but the lack of an equivalent for "pain" in North America. At least "croissant" more or less conveys the flaky pastry.

Answer (score 2):

Puisque la question porte sur le croissant, je n'entrerai pas dans la controverse chocolatine / pain au chocolat.

Si j'entre dans une boulangerie et que je commande un croissant, j'attends qu'on me serve un croissant et rien d'autre, c'est-à-dire [selon Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Croissant_(viennoiserie)) une viennoiserie en forme de croissant à base de pâte levée feuilletée dont la matière grasse est uniquement du beurre.

[Son nom et sa préparation](https://www.patisserie-traditionnelle.com/bases-cap-patisserie/plf/) sont parfaitement codifiés dans le CAP (certificat d'aptitude professionnelle) de pâtisserie.

Donc non, il n'est pas normal en France qu'on serve un pain au chocolat à la place d'un croissant.

Cela dit, il est rare aussi de commander un "croissant au chocolat". Ce n'est pas une viennoiserie traditionnelle, donc pas focément disponible partout et sujette à de multiples interprétations, pouvant aller du pain au chocolat traditionnel à un croissant recouvert de chocolat en passant par un croissant fourré avec une barre ou des pépites de chocolat.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it wouldn't be surprising; French caterers and other providers of food articles to the public are in the habit of taking liberties with accepted terms, those that concern the articles themselves  and as well those of the language in general. Recently, they've introduced the term "gourmand" which means "greedy" as a synonym of "succulent" for a dish, so a "greedy dish" is a succulent dish (aberration); other aberration, they have called blue cheese "fromage persillé", which means cheese in which has been intermingled parsley and there is not a trace of parsley in this particular cheese: the blue matter they refer to, which is blue and not green as is parsley is nothing but mould (Les moisissures : Penicillium camemberti, Penicillium roqueforti, Mucor,...([réf.](http://androuet.com/Des-bact%C3%A9ries-&-des-moisissures-dans-le-fromage...-28-guide-fromage.html)).

One must allow for regional variations, nevertheless. In the case of « pain au chocolat », which is a widespread term in France, people from the South-West  of France say also « chocolatine »;  « croissant au chocolat » is also used although it is much more restricted as a regional term.

Voici plus de détail intéressant provenant de [l'encyclopédie libre](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pain_au_chocolat#Appellations_et_usage) et qui peuvent être encore approfondis à partir de cette page même.

- **pain au chocolat, petit pain ou petit pain au chocolat**, dans la majeure partie de la France, en Suisse, en Algérie et dans une partie de la Belgique ;
- **chocolatine** dans le Sud-Ouest de la France  terme utilisé également au Nouveau-Brunswick et au Québec ;
- **couque au chocolat**, dans la partie nord de la Belgique francophone (dont Bruxelles) ;
- **croissant au chocolat**, parfois en Bourgogne, sporadiquement en Suisse romande, dans certaines provinces du Canada telles que l'Ontario et le Manitoba et au Liban.

  En espagnol, cette viennoiserie se nomme **Napolitana de chocolate**. Réciproquement, **chocolatina** en Espagne (**xocolatina** en catalan) désigne un bonbon au chocolat.

  L'appellation française « **pain au chocolat** » est utilisée en anglais, allemand, italien, ainsi qu'au Japon. La translittération du mot japonais « パン・オ・ショコラ » signifie « pan'oshokora ».

  En 2019, un sondage commandé à l'Ifop par la Fédération des entreprises de boulangerie indique que 84 % des Français désignent ce produit sous le nom « pain au chocolat ».

If you were in Bourgogne, it shouldn't be too surprising, but in another region of France, you  probably met with a case of  popularisation because possibly of the origins of the owners or as inhabitual names are often chosen with a marketing intention in mind.

Comment: Un fromage à pâte persillée est effectivement un fromage avec des traces de "bleu" (qui en plus tire parfois au vert...). Une viande persillée est une viande où le gras est bien visible au sein du muscle. Que cela n'ait rien à voir avec le persil ne change rien au fait que le terme est correct et communément accepté. De plus, n'en déplaise à l'encyclopédie libre, la "couque" (au chocolat, au beurre, aux raisins, et j'en passe) est connue dans toute la Wallonie et Bruxelles. A vrai dire même au nord du pays donc en néerlandais la prononciation est quasi identique.

Comment: @LaurentS. Le terme peut bien être considéré correct par toute la création mais cela ne va pas m'empêcher de refuser de l'utiliser. De même « croissant au chocolat » est une perversion de sens que je ne peux accepter dans mon vocabulaire.

Comment: Que vous refusiez de l'utiliser, c'est votre problème, mais ce ne sont alors pas les industriels qui prennent des libertés, c'est vous qui décidez de limiter les vôtres. Le terme "pâte persillée" pour se rapporter au fromage se retrouve jusque dans [des ouvrages bi-centenaires](https://books.google.be/books?id=4eApAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA433&dq=%22p%C3%A2te+persill%C3%A9e%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwijw_Cq1urmAhWvPOwKHXZVAIoQ6AEIMTAB#v=onepage&q=%22p%C3%A2te%20persill%C3%A9e%22&f=false). Quant au terme "croissant au chocolat", s'il s'agit effectivement d'un croissant avec du chocolat, pourquoi pas ?

Comment: @LaurentS. Le fait qu'une pratique ait été acceptée et perpétrée pendant des générations, que ce soit dans le domaine de la langue ou autre, n'est pas une raison suffisante pour la rendre immune à tout changement, à innocenter les irresponsables qui ont pu la permettre. On change tous les pours des pratiques anciennes, pas moins dans le domaine de la langue qu'ailleurs, parce qu'elles ne conviennent pas. Dans le cas du véritable croissant (qui garde sa forme), non, je ne vois pas de problème, bien sûr: c'est un croissant auquel on a ajouté du chocolat (c'est très bien de le nommer ainsi).

Comment: @LaurentS. Je devrais dire plutôt « les irresponsables ou les non avertis du fait de l'ignorance inéluctablement associée aux âges antérieurs ».

Comment: @LaurentS: une étude très sérieuse montre que le terme "couque au chocolat" n'est effectivement pas utilisé dans toute la Belgique francophone (cf carte ici: https://francaisdenosregions.com/2016/09/01/pain-au-chocolat-ou-chocolatine/). De ma propre expérience personnelle de locuteur bruxelllois: on m'a déjà demandé de confirmer ce que j'entendais par "couque au chocolat" dans une boulangerie à Virton, et ma famille du côté de Philippeville me taxe (gentiment) de "péteux de brusseleir" quand ils ont m'entendent utiliser ce terme...

Comment: @Greg merci de cette info et de ce témoignage. J'avoue être assez surpris, je n'ai moi-même jamais rencontré de telles réactions de Tournai à Liège, sans doute ai-je été chanceux, ou mes interlocuteurs ont préféré ne pas me reprendre :-)

Comment: Traduire "Gourmand" par "greedy" est un abus de langage, vu qu'il retire toute la notion culinaire/gastronomique et en fait un synonyme stricte de "avide". La digression sur les mets "persillés" est inutile pour la réponse. Je confirme qu'en Suisse, un croissant au chocolat est un croissant avec une barre de chocolat dedans... Mais il y perd souvent la forme de croissant.

Comment: @MakorDal You ignore my point completely: this is no translation. There is no digression, more of the same thing: undesirable words in the language, that being due to inappropriate coining.

Comment: Concerning @MakorDal 's 1st objection, s/he could be referring to your unqualified claim that "...the term 'gourmand'.. **means** (i.e., '**translates** to') 'greedy'..." Since "gourmand" **can** mean "greedy" (according to some translations), using "abus de langage" might be an exaggeration (or even an "abus de langage" itself), but your choice to supply only the "greedy" sense of "gourmand" to bolster your claim that "greedy dish" is an aberration (instead of its "gluttonous/self-indulgent [dish]" sense, which in this context wouldn't be aberrant) is, imo, a logical fallacy in your argument.

Comment: @PapaPoule I must say again, as my quotes indicate, that I didn't mean that as a translation. The underlying point of view is philosophical, on the level of word coining.

Comment: Pour le non sequitur et l'ensemble du premier paragraphe. Le traitement paresseux de ces sujets induit en erreur à mon avis. D'où mon vote.