# L'emploi de « persillé » dans le « fromage persillé » est-il incongru ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, origine-ou-raison, métaphore

Dans une réponse on établit un parallèle entre un emploi très particulier de l'adjectif *gourmand* [décrié](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/DNP0322) par l'Académie et l'emploi de [*persillé*](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9P1698) sans son persil, particulièrement dans *fromage persillé* pour identifier l'emploi comme une « aberration » :

> Recently, they've introduced the term "gourmand" which means "greedy"
>   as a synonym of "succulent" for a dish, so a "greedy dish" is a
>   succulent dish (aberration); other aberration, they have called blue
>   cheese "fromage persillé", which means cheese in which has been
>   intermingled parsley and there is not a trace of parsley in this
>   particular cheese: the blue matter they refer to, which is blue and
>   not green as is parsley is nothing but mould [...]
>
> [ [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/40808) de LPH, sur French Language Stack Exchange, cc by-sa ]

L'emploi de *persillé* quand le persil est absent est-il récent et généralement condamné ; constitue-t-il une aberration linguistique [incongrue](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/incongru) et qui heurterait de plein fouet la sensibilité du locuteur francophone ?

Answer (score 3):

> PERSILLÉ, ÉE, adj. (1694) qualifie un fromage présentant des
>   moisissures vertes, par analogie d'aspect avec la plante telle qu'elle
>   est utilisée en cuisine. Cet adjectif peut se confondre avec le
>   participe passé adjectivé de PERSILLER v. tr. (1694) « garnir de
>   persil » et au figuré « de qqch. », son participe passé qualifiant une
>   préparation accompagnée de persil (1830, bouilli persillé). [...] ◆
>   Persillé est substantivé pour la fermentation à l'intérieur de
>   certains fromages (1895), donnant son nom à un fromage (1398 ,
>   persillé de Savoie) ; en boucherie, il désigne un morceau (surtout de
>   boeuf) dont la viande est parsemée d'infiltrations graisseuses (1911),
>   emploi vivant aussi pour l'adjectif (entrecôte persillée).
>
> [ Dictionnaire historique de la langue française, sup. Rey, Larousse,
>   2011, « persillé » ]

On trouve entre autres, au *Grand Larousse gastronomique* (2007) :

> BLEU OU PERSILLÉ. Nom générique des fromages à pâte fleurie dite «
>   persillée » provenant des régions montagneuses (Jura, Massif central,
>   Alpes).
>
> • [familles] FROMAGES A PÂTE PERSILLÉE. Le caillé est découpé après le
>   caillage, parfois légèrement brassé, puis ensemencé en moisissures
>   (qui donnent les veinures) avant le moulage et l'affinage. Durant ce
>   dernier, le « bleu » se développe dans les cavités du caillé ou le
>   long des piqûres faites dans la pâte (veines).
>
> PERSILLÉ. Se dit de fromages comportant des moisissures internes
>   vert-bleu. Pour certains d'entre eux, le mot est utilisé comme
>   appellation. [...] Ces fromages à pâte molle sont en grande majorité
>   au lait de vache, le roquefort (brebis) constituant une exception.
>   Leur pâte est ensemencée de moisissures et transpercée à l'aide de
>   longues aiguilles fines pour favoriser le développement des marbrures.
>   Les persillés ont besoin d'un affinage long et minutieux dans des
>   caves très humides (de 2 à 6 mois selon les formes et les tailles).
>
> PERSILLÉ DES ARAVIS. Fromage savoyard de lait de vache (45 % de
>   matières grasses), à pâte molle veinée de vert et à croûte naturelle.
>   Il se présente sous la forme d'un cylindre de 8 à 10 cm de diamètre et
>   de 12 à 15 cm d'épaisseur, et pèse 1 kg. Le persillé de Thônes et le
>   persillé du Grand-Bornand, très proches, sont comme lui fabriqués à la
>   ferme et ont la même saveur relevée.
>
> [ Grand Larousse gastronomique, Les Éditions Larousse, 2007, « bleu ou
>   persillé », « fromages à pâte persillée », « persillé », « persillé
>   des aravis ». ]

Voir aussi au [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/persill%C3%A9/1), « Roquefort bien persillé ».

---

Non, c'est employé depuis l'[époque](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/1694_en_France) de *Pierre LeMoyne d'Iberville* pour qualifier un fromage... Non, c'est parfaitement adéquat et cohérent car on a l'« analogie d'aspect avec la plante telle qu'elle est utilisée en cuisine » (DHLF). Personne n'est surpris car il s'agit du fait français.